# How can I match multiple elements enclosed in corner brackets with python regex?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, cjk

I have some strings that look like this:

```
<a href="javascript:updateParent('higashino/index.html')">東野 圭吾「夢幻花」「白夜行」</a>他<br>
```

Now I want to extract the link and the strings inside the corner brackets ("「" and "」"), like this:

```
['higashino/index.html', '夢幻花', '白夜行']
```

I've tried:

```
import re
str = u'''<a href="javascript:updateParent('higashino/index.html')">東野 圭 吾「夢幻花」「白夜行」</a>他<br>'''
myre = re.compile(ur'''\('(.*)'\)">.*「(.*?)」.*''', re.UNICODE)
myre.findall(str)
```

the result is:

```
['higashino/index.html', '白夜行']
```

then I tried to use the pattern`\('(.*)'\)">.*「([^」]*)」.*`, but the result was the same, only one element inside the corner brackets was found.

How can I get not just one, but all elements inside the corner brackets? Thanks.

Comment: The reason you only get one match is that `re.findall` returns all matches for *the regex* and the regex you have only matches once. (It could match two different ways, but there is only one match for `'\)">` and hence for the entire expression.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `re.findall()` (or `re.finditer`) with the regex `「([^」]*?)」`:

```
import re
str = '''<a href="javascript:updateParent('higashino/index.html')">東野 圭 吾「夢幻花」「白夜行」</a>他<br>'''
match = re.findall(r'「([^」]*?)」', str)
print(match)
```

Giving:

```
['夢幻花', '白夜行']
```

Using python 3.
Also, if you're not using python 3 already I recommend doing so as it is much better with unicode strings than python 2

Comment: Thanks for the advice! One more reason to move to python 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> myre = re.compile(ur'''(?<=\(').+?(?='\)">)|(?<=「)[^」]+''', re.UNICODE)
>>> myre.findall(str)
[u'higashino/index.html', u'\u5922\u5e7b\u82b1', u'\u767d\u591c\u884c']
```